# Make a TCP request with the broadcast IP adr and a MAC adr

Tags: networking, tcp, modbus

I would like to send a TCP request (Modbus TCP) to a device which has its IP adr not yet set (IP adr = default IP = 0.0.0.0) but which I know its MAC address.
Could I use a "raw" frame ("raw socket", in the TCP header) in order to communicate with this device by using the IP broadcast address (255.255.255.255) and its MAC address ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No. A Modbus TCP slave waits for TCP connections on port 502, and unless customized by the vendor, will not handle raw frames.